# Do Thomas and his friends do anything besides start the rusted wheel of things?

Tags: resources

The melody of the theme song of the cartoon series “Thomas and his friends” matches the scansion of poem X (“March”) of A.E. Housman’s “A Shropshire Lad”. There are five verses to Housman’s poem, but the second one seems especially apt semantically/satirically:

> So braver notes the storm-cock sings
>
> To start the rusted wheel of things,
>
> And brutes in field and brutes in pen
>
> Leap that the world goes round again.

Are there any other poems whose scansion matches this one?

Comment: This is a lovely question, but I fear it’s rather off-topic (hence I’m voting to close): it’s a question of literature and poetics, not English usage.  If’m not sure I can think of a better forum, but if you find one, please link to it here; I’d love to join a discussion about this somewhere else :-)

Comment: Rhyme scheme is very close to being on topic...but possibly not enough. is there a literature.SE? or does writers.SE care about poetry?

Comment: There wasn't in 2011, but now there is a literature SE ... https://literature.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

[**Iambic tetrameter:**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iambic_tetrameter)

A slightly closer to on-topic version of the question might have been: "What is this poetic meter called"?  But even that is probably not good for this site.